# PixyCam (CMUCam5) Serial Printing Out Weird Stuff?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I was trying to get color x and y coordinates from a PixyCam that was connected to an Arduino, everything works fine, but when i open the serial port, it outputs numbers and letters that are not even in the code.

Example of what it does:

```
b(a right arrow) (tabbed over 2 times) 96
q(2 right arrows) (tabbed over once) 183
p(no arrows) (tabbed once) 52 (tabbed 2 times) 105
```

What I aimed to make it do:

```
    X        y
    ~        ~
 B:182       5
 P:23        82
 O:62        140
```

Here is my code

```
Pixy pixy;

void setup() 
{
  //Put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Starting...\n");
  Serial.print("\t\n X \t Y");
  Serial.print("\t\n ~ \t ~\n");
  pixy.init();
}
void loop() 
{
  int blocks = pixy.getBlocks();
  if(pixy.getBlocks())
  {

    //For the color red
    if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 1)
    {

      Serial.print("R:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

    //For the color Orange
       else if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 2)
    {

      Serial.print("O:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

    //For the color Yellow
       else if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 3)
    {

      Serial.print("Y:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

    //For the color Green
       else if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 4)
    {

      Serial.print("G:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

    //For the color Cyan
       else if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 5)
    {

      Serial.print("C:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

    //For the color Blue
       else if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 6)
    {

      Serial.print("B:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

    //For the color Violet
       else if (pixy.blocks[0].signature == 7)
    {

      Serial.print("V:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(pixy.blocks[0].y);
      delay(500);
    }

  }

}
```

Sorry if the code is mediocre, I am new to using/programming for Arduino's.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting up each of the lines:

```
Serial.print("R:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
Serial.print("O:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
Serial.print("Y:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
Serial.print("G:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
Serial.print("C:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
Serial.print("B:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
Serial.print("V:\t"+ pixy.blocks[0].x);
```

into (for example):

```
Serial.print("R:\t");
Serial.print(pixy.blocks[0].x);
```

I suspect `pixy.blocks[0].x` is returning an integer. When you add an integer to a string in C it (counterintuitively, perhaps) counts that number of characters through the string. As this would be off the end of the `"R:\t"` string it causes `Serial.print()` to output random characters from the Arduino memory. Splitting the calls in two allows the integer portion to be printed correctly.

Comment: I found the solution, and I answered my own question with the help of a friend. I hope i got everything down correctly considering that was how he explained it to me. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I know I'm 4 years late, but how do you do this on the PixyCam2? I get a `Pixy2 has no member named blocks` error with exit status 1.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out what was wrong. It is always recommended adding your text to a character(char) array. Then print the buffer (called 'buf' in sample code) that has your text stored in it. Also, adding a delay (Commented out) Help's with a smooth serial print.

```
char buf[32];     //Hold's 32 characters, or so I was told?
sprintf(buf,"Your data goes here %d",pixy.getBlock[0]);//Grabs block zero's data
//delay(500); <<< In milliseconds
Serial.print(buf);
```